Drastic Throughput Reduction with ScriptMediator in WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0
I am currently using WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0, and during my performance testing, I have encountered a significant reduction in throughput when using the ScriptMediator in my flow.
Without the ScriptMediator, I am achieving a throughput of around 4500-5000 transactions per second. However, when I incorporate the ScriptMediator, the throughput drops dramatically to approximately 300 transactions per second. This issue persists regardless of whether I use the JavaScript or Groovy script engines.The throughput reduction is significant and impacts the performance of my integration flows. I am trying to understand the root cause of this reduction when using the ScriptMediator and seeking advice on mitigating this issue.What could be the reasons for such a drastic reduction in throughput when using the ScriptMediator?
Are there alternative ways to achieve similar functionality without such a high-performance penalty?
Has anyone else encountered similar issues, and if so, how did you resolve them?
Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

This depends on what you are really doing within the script mediator. If performance is a concern the recommended approach is to create a Class Mediator to perform whatever functionality you need. You can read ore from here.
